# remix does not populate all functions

Tags: solidity, remix, testing

I complied my code in remix and went to run to test some functions. The functions that populated are accessible but I cannot see all of the functions. For example, _mintTitle() did not populate and there is no button or input field in remix for this function. There are others missing as well. I would like to try to call the functions as a command by typing them at the bottom but that doesn't work either.

```
    function _mintTitle(string _labName) private {}
```

Comment: I don't see any bugs in your code.

Comment: sorry, i added some code from the missing function _mintTitle()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix only generates buttons for functions that are visible to a client. This means `external` and `public` functions will have executable actions, but `internal` and `private` will not.

Comment: after changing _mintTitle() to public and recompiling the button has still failed to populate. is it possible to call the functions in the terminal at the bottom of the page? it does appear that all of the functions that were missing were either internal or private and so we are definitely on the right track.

Comment: You can’t just recompile. You also have to redeploy.

Comment: REMIX ide is not showing external functions to me